# how to read numerical values as a numeric object in r

Tags: r, class, import

I've a table with a column with some text and a column with some numbers. My question is: how to read this table such that the column with characters becomes a column character and the numerical column becomes a numeric column.

Comment: If it is reading a `.txt` or `.csv` file, have you tried `read.table` or `read.csv`

Comment: Based on the description of your data you should get those column types by default, unless something else is going on such as mixed numbers + characters in a column. You need to supply an example of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to `split` the column by a grouping variable.  Here, an easier option is to convert the `character` column (if it is a `factor` column -  convert to `character` class with `as.character`) to `numeric` so that all the non-numeric elements will be `NA`, then using `is.na` convert to logical vector and `split` the original column into a `list` of `vector`.  This can be converted back to a data.frame after correcting for the `length` by padding `NA`s at the end.

```
lst1 <- with(df1, split(col, !is.na(as.numeric(col))))
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
out <- data.frame(lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
out <- type.convert(out, as.is = TRUE)
names(out) <- paste0("col", seq_along(out))
str(out)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ col1: chr  "A" "D" "eff1" NA
# $ col2: int  1 2 3 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col = c(1, 2, 3, 'A', 4, 'D', 'eff1'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I don't think the OP has a column with mixed numbers and characters. They say "a column with some text and a column with some numbers."

Comment: @neilfws  I think the OP wanted this solution.  Can you please remove your comments

Comment: Sure. When the OP clarifies.